# c# razor pages multi tenant app - best way to store tenant global variables

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have inherited a multi-tenant c# razor webpages app (NOT MVC and NOT the newer .Net razor pages). The tenants are separated by their URL and on _pagestart the various variables are pulled from the database using the URL. I need to persist this data from page to page.

I cant use the Application store (AppState / App.) because that is application wide and it will all get mixed up.

So apart from the Session object are there any other choices that are like AppState and have more options/syntactic sugar than the straight session object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a global method that resolves current tenant in following order:

- from a claim of authenticated user - just add a claim upon login and then use it. You could possibly use this to verify if tenant from  the claim equals to the tenant from the url. If not, signal this and possibly logout user
- from url when user is not yet authenticated - store in the Items container to speed up lookups during the request. It's not unsafe for unauthenticated users to switch tenants.

No matter what path is used during evaluation, evaluate per-request, do not use a session container.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not familiar with a 'global methods' if they are a distinct thing...I have used static classes before but these are app wide so no good for per request stuff. I could create a non static method but then I would have to invoke it on every page. Thanks

Comment: By a global method I mean global public static method somewhere down the stack so it's easily globally available.

Comment: oh and why do you say dont use the session at all, it seems a suitable container for per request information..?

Comment: Not really, the Items container is suitable for per request data.

Comment: Sounds like you never used it (?), if so, here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.items?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I guess what I am asking (just for my understanding) is is there any difference (performance/reliability etc) between setting session variables on each request (so they essentially become per request containers) or using the HttpContext.Current.Items and setting those on each request. Thanks

Comment: Reliability is equal. Session however is persistent between requests which means it takes resources at the server. The more users using your site the more memory wasted on session data. Items container is cleared just after request is completed. This means that it effectively doesn't take resources at the server.